# what is "emergency_buffer"?

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm doing some coredump debugging, when I printed the content of a string variable, I got this:

```
$8 = {static npos = 18446744073709551615, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
    _M_p = 0x7f25c1a48d98 <emergency_buffer+7464> ""}}
```

I want to know what does the "emergency_buffer" mean here? Thanks.

Comment: It is just the symbol that happens to be closest to that address. There is no real significance to it.

Comment: The symbol is part of the runtime's exception handling. If a program throws an exception because it has run out of free memory, where do you put that exception? In the  `emergency_buffer`